# How to use integers in write command in turtle module python

Tags: python, integer, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to use integers in the write command.

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
a=0
b=0
t.write(a,':',b)
```

When I run this code it shows these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Drukker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Among_us.py", line 5, in <module>
    t.write(a,':',b)
  File "C:\Users\Drukker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 3432, in write
    end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?
Thanks

Comment: If anyone has an answer please tell me!!!

Comment: If there was anything that you didn't understand please tell to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the write function properly.

The syntax of the function is:

`turtle.write(arg, move=False, align=’left’, font=(‘Arial’, 8, ‘normal’))`

Your arguments have to be passed as one parameter, so I believe what you are trying to do is:

`t.write(str(a) + ':' + str(b))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use one string as the parameter.
Try;

```
t.write(str(a)+':'+str(b))
```